# replace CamelCase function argument with SNAKE_CASE

Tags: regex, sed

I have a huge number of source files that have the ctor initialized as below:

```
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar("CamelCaseArgument") {}
```

I have to replace the "CamelCaseArgument" with CAMEL_CASE_ARGUMENT

So the result should be

```
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar(CAMEL_CASE_ARGUMENT) {}
```

Foo and CamelCaseArgument are varying, Bar is a class name so its always the same and can be used as a pattern element,

This task can be easily done using python/perl/php/etc but I was curious if this can be handled with sed,
My initial idea was to use gnu sed in 2 rounds,

1) removing " chars,

```
$ echo 'Foo::Foo() : Bar("CamelCaseArgument") {}' | sed -rne 's/(Bar.{1})(["])([[:alpha:]]*)(["])/\1\3/gip'
Foo::Foo() : Bar(CamelCaseArgument) {}
```

2) transforming CamelCaseArgument => CAMEL_CASE_ARGUMENT

I don't know how to output all the matching parts not only the last one

My current(not working) formula:

```
$ echo 'Foo::Foo() : Bar(CamelCaseArgument) {}' | sed -rn 's/Bar.{1}([A-Z][a-z]*)+/\0\U\1_/gp'
Foo::Foo() : Bar(CamelCaseArgument_ARGUMENT) {}
```

Comment: Could you please do mention here is it a fixed string which you want to perform this operation? Or there is something like we have some condition and string could be any other string too, kindly confirm once?

Comment: as in the problem description "Foo and CamelCaseArgument are varying,..."  CamelCaseArgument  is changing with every file, only Bar is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is not intended for complex tasks like this, use perl, awk, etc. instead. Since you've asked for a sed solution and nobody came up with one yet I'm sharing this workaround.

```
$ cat file
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar("CamelCaseArgument") {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar("ThisIsATest") {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Baz("ThisIsATest") {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar("Camel") {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar("") {}
$
$ cat tst.sed
s/\<Bar("/Bar(\n/; t1; b
:1
    s/\n\([A-Z][a-z]*\)/\U\1_\n/; t1
# clean up
s/_\?\n"//
$
$ sed -f tst.sed file
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar(CAMEL_CASE_ARGUMENT) {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar(THIS_IS_A_TEST) {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Baz("ThisIsATest") {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar(CAMEL) {}
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar() {}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe '
    s{"((?:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+){2,})"}{
        join "_", map {uc} ($1 =~ /[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+/g)
    }eg
' <<END
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar("CamelCaseArgument") {}
END
```

```
Foo::Foo(...) : Bar(CAMEL_CASE_ARGUMENT) {}
```

If you want to filter on `Bar`, then use this regex:

```
Bar\(\K"((?:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+){2,})"
```

Comment: golf: `perl -pe's{"((?:[A-Z][a-z]+){2,})"}{join"_",map{uc}$1=~/[A-Z][a-z]+/g}eg'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(Bar(\)"\([^"]\+\)"/\1\n\2\n/g;T;:a;s/_\n\n//g;ta;s/\n\([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*\)/\U\1_\n/g;ta' file
```

Surround any non-empty double quoted strings with newlines that are preceded by `Bar(`. Iterate through ou the above strings, insert an underscore following any lowercase letters and then capitalize the strings (removing the last underscore and the introduced newlines).